# On unity3d, my IBM chatbot can't recognize sequential

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

It is another unity watson sdk question.
I solved the first talk issue by just make fake object again..
Here is another thing.

In my chatbot I can see sequential text if there are same intents.

What line do I have to change or add to make it happen?

(another question: What line do I have to change or add to bring 'jump to' method in my unity?

```
using IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Services.Conversation.v1;
using IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Utilities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

class Watson : MonoBehaviour{    
static Credentials credentials;
static Conversation _conversation;
void Start()
{
    credentials = new Credentials("xx-xx-xx-xx-xx", "xx", "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api");
  //  credentials.Url = "";
    _conversation = new Conversation(credentials);

}
static Action<string, ManagerChat.Feel, bool> Act;
public static void GoMessage(string _str,Action<string, ManagerChat.Feel,bool> _act)
{

    if (!_conversation.Message(OnMessage, "xx-xx-xx-xx-xx", _str))
        Debug.Log("ExampleConversation Failed to message!");

    Act = _act;
}

static bool GetIntent(Dictionary<string, object> respDict)
{
    object intents;
    respDict.TryGetValue("intents", out intents);

    object intentString = new object();

    object confidenceString = new object();

    foreach (var intentObj in (intents as List<object>))
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> intentDict = intentObj as Dictionary<string, object>;

        intentDict.TryGetValue("intent", out intentString);


        intentDict.TryGetValue("confidence", out confidenceString);
    }
    string str = intentString as string;

    if (str == "6사용자_마무리")
        return true;

    return false;

}

static string GetOutput(Dictionary<string, object> respDict)
{
    object outputs;
    respDict.TryGetValue("output", out outputs);

    object output;
    (outputs as Dictionary<string, object>).TryGetValue("text", out output);

    string var = (output as List<object>)[0] as string;

    return var;
}

static ManagerChat.Feel GetEntities(Dictionary<string, object> respDict)
{
    object entities;
    respDict.TryGetValue("entities", out entities);

    List<object> entitieList = (entities as List<object>);

    if(entitieList.Count == 0)
    {
        return ManagerChat.Feel.Normal;
    }
    else
    {
        object entitie;
        (entitieList[0] as Dictionary<string, object>).TryGetValue("value", out entitie);
        ManagerChat.Feel feel = ManagerChat.Feel.NONE;

        string str = entitie as string;

        switch (str)
        {
            case "Happy":
                feel = ManagerChat.Feel.Happy;
                break;
            case "Expect":
                feel = ManagerChat.Feel.Expect;
                break;
            case "Born":
                feel = ManagerChat.Feel.Born;
                break;
            case "Sad":
                feel = ManagerChat.Feel.Sad;
                break;
            case "Surprise":
                feel = ManagerChat.Feel.Surprise;
                break;
            case "Normal":
                feel = ManagerChat.Feel.Normal;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return feel;
    }
}

static void OnMessage(object resp, string data)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> respDict = resp as Dictionary<string, object>;

  bool flag = (GetIntent(respDict));

    string output = (GetOutput(respDict));

   ManagerChat.Feel feel = GetEntities(respDict);
  //      Debug.Log(resp);
  //      Debug.Log(data);
        Act(output,feel, flag);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite follow your question about sequential texts, but I think you may be trying to do more in your application code than is needed. 
I'll just give a high level pattern about how to use the sdk and see if that clears things up. Im no Unity dev, but the pattern is the same no matter the language. 
You only need to give Watson the user's input text, and the existing context variables, most importantly system context, but any custom context you have created is valuable as well. 
Then, Watson will return an output.text object, which you post to the user, and Watson also returns an updated system context. 
Next, the user types something new, your app grabs that text, passes it to Watson along with the context object he returned last time, and the process repeats.

You should not need to do anything in your app code for jump tos, sequential text, etc., as thats all handled by Watson.

The only feature I can think of for the sequential piece is the response variations for a single dialog node. This feature means that if a user visits a specific dialog node multiple times, you will give different reponses, either in seuqential order, or random order, if there are multiple. It does require more than one input from the user, navigating to the same node multiple times. This is to give your bot some variation, most valuable for common inputs like 'hello', 'googbye', 'thanks', etc.